# jquery mobile dialog transition right to left?

Tags: jquery-mobile, css-transitions

I need to create the "Facebook iPad" look and feel using jQueryMobile.
I have a little question:
How to "stack" a page over the current page of my app from right to left?
(I need to mimic the same effect, when you want to reach an user page, means, the new page "overlays" the current one.. and so so.. 
if I click (or tap) to a link from the "stacked" page, I want a new one comes from right to left and "cover" the last staked page... 
If close the latest inserted page, I want an slide effect from right to left and (destroy the closed page)
Any help?
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U just need jquery-mobile [**transition**](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4/docs/pages/docs-transitions.html) effect & open the new page via AJAX technique-

```
<a href="newPage.html" data-transition="slide" >It will Slide</a>
```

U can put `rel="external" or data-ajax="false"` - to open as full page reload, without AJAX